# How could i convert the 3dmax file into flash?

Tags: 3d, swiftmailer, 3dsmax

I want to place a 3d rotaional animation on to my website. I have designed those in 3dmax/swift 3d. I need to convert those files to flash.

Are there any possibilities to place the 3d max file directly into webpage?

Answer (score 0):

*Are there any possibilities to place the 3d max file directly into webpage?*

No.

You need an exporter to do this, or render out as image sequence and assemble it in flash.

Comment: Thanx for your idea , i am going on it

Answer (score 0):

Look into using Papervision3D (to get the 3D into Flash, which is the only plugin required of the user) and OpenCollada (to export the models from 3ds max into a format that Papervision3D can read).

Answer (score 0):

In Maya you can render with the `Vector renderer` e.g. [3d Helicopter](http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/maya2012/en_us/index.html?url=files/About_rendering_and_renderers_Maya_Vector_renderer.htm,topicNumber=d28e569753).  I don't know if Max has vector render, but you can download a Maya trial and import the Max file.